# SDL_TTF : undefined reference to "TTF_INIT"

Tags: c, linker, sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to learn how to use SDL_TTF library. But i'm unable to solve an error of type : 
*undefined reference to "TTF_INIT"*

here is the simple code that im trying to compile and use :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   TTF_INIT();
   TTF_Quit();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is CFLAGS of my makefile :

```
CFLAGS= `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`-lSDL2_ttf
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

PS: i used `sudo apt` to install SDL2 and SDL2_TTF

Comment: What are these backticks in the `CFLAGS` line?

Comment: It is a rule.. (that's what i learnt.. it may be wrong, but it doesn't work without it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are missing a space after your last backtick in `CFLAGS`. Even then, it should look more like:

```
CFLAGS=`sdl2-config --cflags`
LFLAGS=`sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2_ttf
```

Also, `TTF_Init()` (note that it's not all caps) must come after `SDL_Init()`.

Check out LazyFoo's tutorial all about this at http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/index.php . You may want to start at the beginning, though (http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php).

edit: I thought I'd mention from the comments that while backticks work, it's more common to write `$(shell sdl2-config --cflags)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably already solved it, but I got to this page and no, TTF_Init() doesn't need to come after SDL_Init as @contrapants sugested, as we can see in the chapter 2.2 of the [manual](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.pdf#TTF_Init).

So the problem with your code was really writing TTF_Init() in CAPS and missing the space between ` and -.